# Multiple forks does not work

Tags: c++, c, fork

I am trying to create 5 children and 1 parent. But the parent will create them (at least 4 of them. Because first we need to fork) but it creates bunch of children. Cannot find what i am doing wrong. Any idea please?

```
child0=fork();//first process
if(child0>0)//Parent
{

    //Create children
    child1=fork();
    child2=fork();
    child3=fork();
    child4=fork();
    cout<<"i am child 0 "<<child0 <<"  ";
    cout<<"i am child 1 "<<child1;
    cout<<"i am child 2 "<<child2;
    cout<<"i am child 3 "<<child3;
    cout<<"i am child 4 "<<child4;
    wait(child0);
    wait(child1);
    wait(child2);
    wait(child3);
    wait(child4);
}
else if(child0<0)
{
    printf("fork() failed!\n");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
cout<<"i am child0";
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You perform a lot of forking without checking the returned id. a lot of children are also forking more children.

Answer (score 4):

After every fork you double the number of the processess. This your code:

```
child1=fork(); // we have two now
child2=fork(); // each one of them forks - we have 4
child3=fork(); // 8
child4=fork(); // 16
```

You need to check the return value of the fork. When it is non-0, you are in the parent, and can fork again. If it is 0, you are child, and thou shall not `fork()` - should do your child chores.

And while you are on checking the return value, you might as well check it for `-1` - this means the `fork()` failed. As unbelieavable as it seems, I know a production system where this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember -- When you do fork(), both child and parent again start execution from the next line of fork() statement. fork() returns 0 in the child process and PID of the child in the parent process. Hence in you case the child and parent both of them again fork. You are creating a tree of processes.

So do in this manner

```
int pid;
if((pid=fork())==0)
{
  // Child Process
  printf("I'm child");
}
else
{
   // Parent process
   // Again do fork() here
}
```